# Movie about hostile robots disguised as footballs

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this on TV in mid 90s I think.
One or more people travel to another celestial body (might or might not be the/a moon or mars), they find an American football. The football transforms into a robot that is hostile. They later find LOTS of these footballs/disguised robots.

Since there are lots of robotic projects with "football robots" or "[hand-egg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzWz3.jpg) robots", it is very hard to filter search results using Google etc.

Comment: I think you mean "[hand-egg](http://cdn2.sbnation.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/6464387/handegg.0_standard_709.0.jpg)"

Comment: @Richard yes, thank you

Comment: I suggest you undo that change - @Richard was making a joke.

Comment: @Wikis i know this, as i am german and for me, a "football" is the black&white/spherical thing. i think "hand-egg" is clear to everyone, even though it's actually a joke - right? i will reverse the question title though

Comment: Sure..........!

Comment: Fixed the question to mention hand-egg, but to indivcate its an "American football". There's a fellow asking about a robot building itself up from a football shaped head at http://www.onlygoodmovies.com/blog/movie-megalists/top-85-robot-movies/, "There is this robot, which build it self from his ‘football head’ up to an deadly machine. In one scene you see this robot taking swatches with a little buzz saw and putting them into a bowl. It would be great if someone could help." No answer to him, but in case that's an additional detail...

Comment: @SeanDuggan thank you for the improvement. I do not remind this scene, but i guess it is the same movie though - the head might still had the football surface in robot form, but i am not sure

Comment: It could be entirely unrelated, but whenever I do a Google search and come upon tenuous ties, I like to mention them in case it spurs a "Oh hey... I *do* remember that" moment. :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe [*Moontrap* (1989)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moontrap)?

> On July 20, 1969, during the last phase of the Apollo 11 mission to
>   the Moon, a robotic eye emerges from the lunar soil and takes notice
>   of the landing module as it takes off. The eye buries itself again.
>
> Decades later the Space Shuttle Camelot encounters a derelict
>   spaceship in orbit around Earth. Mission commander Colonel Jason Grant
>   (Walter Koenig) leaves the shuttle to investigate. He discovers a
>   reddish-brown pod and a mummified human corpse. Both things are
>   brought back to Earth, where it is found that they originated on the
>   Moon some fourteen thousand years ago. Shortly thereafter, while being
>   unattended, the pod comes to life. It builds itself a cybernetic body
>   with parts from the lab and pieces of the ancient corpse. The cyborg
>   kills a lab technician and exchanges fire with security guards before
>   Grant destroys it with a shotgun blast to the head.
>
> Using the last completed Apollo rocket, Grant and fellow astronaut Ray
>   Tanner (Bruce Campbell) go to the Moon on a search-and-destroy
>   mission. They discover the ruins of an ancient human civilization.
>   Inside, they find a woman in suspended animation who identifies
>   herself in a rudimentary fashion as Mera (Leigh Lombardi). Mera later
>   reveals the name of the killer cyborgs — the Kaalium. They survive the
>   attack of a spider Kaalium and return to the landing module, with Mera
>   wearing her own spacesuit but it turns out that the Kaalium have
>   stolen the module. The Kaalium also shoot down the command module,
>   leaving the astronauts stranded on the Moon. In subsequent attacks by
>   the Kaalium, Tanner is killed, Grant and Mera are taken prisoner, and
>   the Kaalium head to Earth.
>
> Grant frees himself and rescues Mera from certain death at the hands
>   of a cyborg. In the meantime, the Space Shuttle Intrepid is launched
>   to intercept the approaching alien ship. Grant and Mera look for the
>   control room and find the landing module, which has been adapted into
>   the alien machinery. Grant supposes the module was the last piece of
>   equipment that the Kaalium needed to complete their ship. He starts
>   the module's self-destruct sequence and as they are attacked by a
>   Kaalium crew member, discovers that he can use his gun as a rocket to
>   get away. He and Mera exit through a breach in the hull. The ship
>   explodes after they have reached safe distance.
>
> Some time later, Grant and Mera are shown as a couple living on Earth.
>   Mera, having learned to speak English, explains that she was put in
>   stasis to warn others about the Kaalium. Grant tells her that she does
>   not have to worry anymore, that it is over and hugs her. One of the
>   pods survived the explosion and is now in a junkyard preparing to
>   build itself a new body....

Football-like pod pics:
[image]
[image]

Cyborg alien: 
[image]

Trailer:

Comment: Definitely matches that other movie that one guy was looking for I mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: yep, that's it! thank you very much! I could have sworn they were footballs, looks a bit different now..

Comment: Moontrap was actually a pretty good flick! Nice effects, pretty female lead, and of course... CHEKOV vs. ASH!!!