# Sci-fi movie from 1980's about killer robot in space

Tags: story-identification, movie

This one is very vague because it's been at least 20+ years since I saw this movie, and I was very young. But it's a sci-fi movie that I believe starts with a mummified/dessicated/skeletal body floating in space, and a ship retrieves what I remember as a reddish, football shaped object from it that turns out to be a killer robot that starts murdering people once it forms itself. This sound at all familiar to anyone?

Comment: @Machavity, it hasn't been confirmed and is therefore not a duplicate, per our duplicate story-id criteria

Comment: @Edlothiad Ah, didn't know the policy. I'll retract it if it's not confirmed

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this is definitely the movie!

Comment: It got accepted now (in comments)

Answer (score 8):

This is likely [Moontrap](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097911/).

[image]

The red "ball" is found on a spaceship in orbit, brought back to Earth, where it hatches and builds itself into a killer robot. The rest of the movie is mostly about Bruce Campbell flying to the moon to fight more of them.

Comment: If this is found to be so, it's a duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81421/identification-movie-about-hostile-robots-disguised-as-footballs/81442#81442