# 1980s movie about Spaceship that turned out to be a robot head

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship, robots

All I remember is a spaceship is found and taken in by a government type place and it turns out to be a head for a giant robot. It's 80s or maybe real early 90s, spaceship has one if not three lights in the middle.

I'm actually posting this for a friend, so I don't have any additional info other than what he described above.

Comment: Spaceballs? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceballs

Comment: @val ivanov was this live action or animated? english language or dubbed? there are definitely more details you can give us...

Comment: I am the friend. Lol this film still eludes me.
I remember some people find what they think is a crashed ship ( these are the main characters) then the government comes in and takes it away. The characters go to sneak around the military compound where they took it. And either it transforms it’s self or they are trying to use the tech to make something .. but it turns into a stop motion robot with the ship as it’s head . And the military starts shooting .. and explosions..etc.. all I can remember .. no not moontrap . (That’s a great film.)

Comment: *[Kronos](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050610?ref_=vp_vi_tt)* matches the title, but it's definitely a 1957 film.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81421/movie-about-hostile-robots-disguised-as-footballs

Answer (score 5):

Seems to be [Moontrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moontrap):

[image]

[image]

[image]

> ...He discovers a reddish-brown pod and a mummified human corpse. Both
> are brought back to Earth, where it is found that they originated  on
> the Moon some fourteen thousand years ago. Shortly thereafter, the
> unattended pod comes to life...

Answer (score 0):

This is far too early of a film to fit a 1980s timeframe, but the 1957 film *[Kronos](https://scififilmfiesta.blogspot.com/2016/03/kronos-1957.html)* is a partial match.

[image: Kronos poster]

> *Kronos* is about a small group of scientists who are investigating what at first appears to be an asteroid that eventually enters the Earth's atmosphere and crashes into the ocean. Soon after a giant machine, christened “Kronos” emerges out of the ocean.

It has the ship (initially thought to be an asteroid) which forms the head of a giant robot, which does indeed look stop-motion animated, and has blinking lights. What does not match is that the ship crashes in the ocean before rising as the robot, with the person sneaking onto the base being the alien-possessed Eliot. It does have the military attacking the robot (including with a nuke), which all fails due to the robot being able to absorb energy. It's also a black-and-white film, which suggests against your idea of it being an 80s film.

### Trailer